# Xubuntu Wallpapers Download?

Tags: xubuntu, downloads

Is there a way I can install the xubuntu 16.04 wallpapers on Ubuntu, or at least download them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This OMGUbuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/winning-xubuntu-16-04-community-wallpapers-beautiful) has links to all the 16.04 Xubuntu wallpaper contest winners.

Here's the official page with the images: https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-16-04-wallpaper-competition-winners/?utm_source=omgubuntu

---

You can also install them:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-wallpapers
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-community-wallpapers
```

(if it exists)

Comment: Hmm thanks, I see that there's looks like to be a possible package name on the xubuntu page at the bottom there. Would I just run: sudo apt-get install xubuntu-community-wallpapers?

Comment: You can try it.

Comment: Hahah nevermind you answered my question as soon as I posted the comment above, thanks!

Comment: Yup it works you just have to add the wallpapers to /usr/share/backgrounds. :)

Comment: There we go! :)